# Windows like window look

Tags: vb.net, windows-shell

I am looking on the internet for two days to create a form with the extended titlebar (to have the left, right and an search-bar) and the sidebar. I extracted 3 background images from shell32.dll that are used in the sidebar.

I'd like to know if I could namespace some shell objects or is there a solution. I really would like to see this happening.

[image: Example screenshot]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Code Project, non-client area](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/55180/Extending-the-Non-Client-Area-in-Aero). I know it's not VB, but maybe enough to glean what you need.

Comment: That is a good lead. However, it is for C#. Is it easy to translate this in VB? What about the two panels (left and right) in the application, any idea how I could get that into production?

Comment: Thank you for the converter. I’ll look into that later.